# How to write a variable name into a file and not its value

Tags: perl, variables

I am new to Perl and I have a basic question.
I need to write a text file that contains the "$" symbol. Example:

`unless(open FILE, '>'.$file){`
`die "Unable to create $file";`
`}`
`print FILE "$tmp\n";`

I want perl to LITERALLY write "$tmp" into my file, and not its value.
In my perl script, I dont want "$tmp" to be a variable... just a string.
When running my script it complains because the variable is not defined. If I define it, it gives the value "0". I know there has to be a way.
I have tried defining the value has text with the same letters, but it does not work:
my $tmp = "$tmp"
I also tried concatenating the "$" simbol and the text; does not work:
my $tmp = "$" . "tmp"

Comment: use single quotes `''` or backslash `\$`

Answer (score 5):

This is about quote interpolation.

Perl handles different types of quotes in different ways.

For example:

```
my $tmp = 'fish';

print $tmp, "\n";
print "$tmp\n";
print '$tmp\n';
print "\n";

print q{$tmp},"\n"
```

Double quotes usually means 'this is a string, but process it first'. That means 'handle' backslashes to escape characters, and expand variables to their values.

Single quotes usually means 'don't process it'.

You can also escape a metacharacter that *would* be interpolated, by prefixing with a backslash. E.g.:

```
print "\$tmp\n";
```

The `q{}` type of quote allows you to use arbitrary delimiters, which is really useful for strings that have quotes in then naturally.

```
my $tmp2 = q{'"/\''"\n};
print $tmp2,"\n";
```

You can also:

```
print q|!"£$%^&*()_|;
print q#!"£$%^&*()_#;
```

(etc.).

As a style point, I would suggest - you should try to use single quotes when you don't have any dynamic content, because it makes clear that it's *not* being interpolated at all. 
`q{}` style quoting is very helpful to for clarifying strings with quotes.

See also:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators